# SHA1 Key mismatch of my app

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore

I am in a real trouble.I have formatted my hard drive. I took  a backup of my Keystore file (.jks). 
I have downloaded my code from Github and "Generate Signed APk" with that keystore(.jks) file.

Now when I try to submit my apk in google play it is saying my SHA1 are different though I used same keystore file.

[image]

Please help me

Comment: You probably saved the wrong keystore file or you are not using the proper alias.

Comment: is there any way to get the alias from the keystore file?

Comment: Android Studio shows you the available aliases in the keystore when you select the keystore file and enter the keystore pass during the APK generation. If it contains multiple, you can select another. But if this is the only one, you're out of luck and will need to create a new keystore / use this one to upload a completely new app (new package name in Play Store), which means that your users will need to download the new app in order to receive updates.

Comment: I got the right keystore. Just wasted 12 hours from life. Thank you @GergelyKőrössy for pointing out the fact

Comment: No problem, glad it got resolved.